# PHP Debugging - Callback

Tags: php, debugging, callback

I have eclipse setup with PHP debugging - that's not a problem.

The problem is that it only debugs scripts I ran via eclipse / browser.

I am working with the Facebook-Credits which causes a call-back to my server (using normal HTTP post).

I am sure there is a way to make my debugger kick into action once the request is received [not via browser], I just haven't found it! :P (I googled this quiet a bit)

If anyone has some tutorial/link that would be great,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using XDebug, it's just a matter of adding the parameter value pair `XDEBUG_SESSION_START=name_of_session` to the query string.

So if you were giving the callback:

```
http://example.com/callback
```

you give instead:

```
http://example.com/callback?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=name_of_session
```

And make sure you have a debugging session running in your IDE so XDebug can connect to it.

Comment: EDIT: Got it, thanks! ---- would this name_of_session be some sort of const? eg "fb_callback" or do I need to set it every time the debugger starts with a new URL? (which is unlikely) -- NM, got it - thanks :)